# define method inside block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to ruby, I'm studying ruby by writing unittest with RSpec, and there is one line of code I can't understand in RSpec when define custom matcher.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    do_the_math(actual, expected)
  end

  def do_the_math(actual, expected)
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end
```

as far as I know, ruby is a script language that the compiler read the code sequencly. that is said you must define the method before you use it. but in RSpec, when I define a custom matcher, I could define the helper method after I call it.

I have write the test code to test the fact that it will fail if I call the method before I define it and I also read a little source code from RSpec the define method actually is a wrapper of define_method and pass the delegate as block. but I still can't understand how this code work.

can somebody help me out? just a brief explaination of how this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short explanation is: you are not calling this method yet in there, you are only saying to call it when you call `be_a_multiple_of` matcher, and the method is already defined when that happens.

Parser is not checking whether methods are defined or not when declaring a method or block - as the method might be defined later or there might be a `missing_method` fall_back.

Comment: thank you for your help, yes, I understand that the outer block will be called until be_a_multiple_of called, but the block is still execute sequencly isn't it? is that because missing_method working behand it? or may be match is a async method and the block will be called after the do_match_math defined?

Comment: It does read it sequentially, not executing them. `Rspec::Matcher.define` method grabs the block and stores it in instance variable for later use - it is not executing it until needed.

Comment: "method grabs the block and stores it in instance variable for later use" right, that's it, thanks for your help, the answer makes me happy

Comment: Actually that is what it does in version I use. Newest version apparently takes the block and converts it into a method using `define_method` method. The result is the same.